# What is the difference between incremental and one-shot compression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, bzip2, lzma

I am trying to use the `bz2` and/or `lzma` packages in python. I am trying to compress a database dump in csv format and then put it to a `zip` file. I got it to work with one-shot compression with both the packages.

Code for which looks like this:

```
with ZipFile('something.zip', 'w') as zf:
    content = bz2.compress(bytes(csv_string, 'UTF-8'))  # also with lzma
    zf.writestr(
        'something.csv' + '.bz2',
        content,
        compress_type=ZIP_DEFLATED
    )
```

When I try to use incremental compression then it creates a .zip file which when I try to extract keeps giving some archive file recursively.

Code for which looks like this:

```
with ZipFile('something.zip', 'w') as zf:
    compressor = bz2.BZ2Compressor()
    content = compressor.compress(bytes(csv_string, 'UTF-8'))  # also with lzma
    zf.writestr(
        'something.csv' + '.bz2',
        content,
        compress_type=ZIP_DEFLATED
    )
    compressor.flush()
```

I went through the documentation and also look for information about the compression techniques, and there seems to be no comprehensive information about what one-shot and incremental compression are.

Comment: You might want to read http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html  &

http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0452 & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_encoding

Comment: Thanks! That helps. One-shot compression is a bit complex to understand quickly.

Comment: You are spending excess time in trying to compress a .bz2 file twice

Comment: I'm puzzled. Your second example would result in a corrupted `something.csv.bz2` but would not have caused any error with the zipfile itself. It should unzip without a problem. BTW, if you want to store the bz2 file in the zipfile, use `ZIP_STORED`. You actually increase the size of the archive if you try to compress twice.

Comment: @adarsh have you found a solution yet ? what are your results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between one-shot and incremental is that with one-shot mode you need to have the entire data in memory; if you are compressing a 100 gigabyte file, you ought to have loads of RAM.

With the incremental encoder your code can feed the compressor 1 megabyte or 1 kilobyte at a time and write whatever data results, into a file as soon as it is available. Another benefit is that an incremental compressor you can use to stream data - you can start writing compressed data before all uncompressed data is available!

---

Your second code is **incorrect** and it will cause you to lose your data. The `flush` may return more data that you need to save as well. Here I am compressing a string of 1000 `'a'` characters in Python 3; the result from `compress` is an empty string; the actual compressed data is returned from `flush`.

```
>>> c = bz2.BZ2Compressor()
>>> c.compress(b'a' * 1000)
b''
>>> c.flush()
b'BZh91AY&SYI\xdcOc\x00\x00\x01\x81\x01\xa0\x00\x00\x80\x00\x08 \x00 
\xaamA\x98\xba\x83\xc5\xdc\x91N\x14$\x12w\x13\xd8\xc0'
```

Thus your second code should be:

```
compressor = bz2.BZ2Compressor()
content = compressor.compress(bytes(csv_string, 'UTF-8'))  # also with lzma
content += compressor.flush()
```

But actually you're still doing the one-shot compression, in a very complicated manner.

Comment: Ah, awesome! Thanks! This totally clears it up for me. Although I want to ask how can I do this in a less complicated manner? What is complicated with my one-shot approach? Also is there any compression advantage of using one of the approaches over the other, going by what's explained here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_encoding?

Comment: No, I mean you are using the incremental encoder to do "one-shot"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i'm still looking for a way to do incremental decompression using LZMA SDK http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html !can you help plz

Comment: @Frankenstein if you have another question then do ask another question.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala actually here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249031/how-to-run-incremental-decompression-in-lzma-sdk