# python: How do bz2 "incremental" and "one-shot" (de)compression differ from the "regular" method?

Tags: python-3.x, compression, pickle, bz2

I have a series of directories, each about 38 MB on disk, that I need to pickle no a Python 3.6 Windows 10 system. When I ran the following the code, the resulting .pickle files were huge, ~158 MB each:

```
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
with open(set_filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dataset, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Is this normal? The pickle is 4 times the size of the original data files.

I then tried `bz2` with `pickle` and the resulting .pkl files were much smaller, ~18 MB:

```
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
import bz2
with bz2.BZ2File(set_filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dataset, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

To decompress and unpickle:

```
with bz2.BZ2File(pickle_file, mode='r') as f:
    letter_set = pickle.load(f)
```

I'm happy with the improvement but would take even better compression if I could find it.

**Questions**:

1. I notice there is also a `bz2.open()` method. So far `bz2.BZ2File()` seems to be working, but when would I want to use `open()` instead?
2. What is the difference between "regular" (de)compression using  `bz2.BZ2File()` and "incremental" (`bz2.BZ2Compressor`()/`bz2.BZ2Decompressor`) and "one-shot" (`bz2.compress`/`bz2.decompress`) (de)compression? I have read the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bz2.html but it doesn't explain these terms or in what cases they might be preferable.

Comment: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258786/what-is-the-difference-between-incremental-and-one-shot-compression)